# why do I have this error deploying firebase simple function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and trying to deploy a basic function to add users to firestore databse

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore()

exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return db
        .collection("user")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))
})
```

I get this error? no idea why it happens

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function newUser(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: functions@undefined
npm ERR! Found: firebase-admin@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-admin
npm ERR!   firebase-admin@"^111.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer firebase-admin@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from firebase-functions@4.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-functions
npm ERR!   firebase-functions@"^4.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-19T06_03_09_079Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: b0ba1f57

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        newUser(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

did anyone face this before or how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your package.json file and ensure you have run npm install.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase-admin](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases/tag/v11.5.0) is currently on version `11.5`. Your error is stating that it can't find version `115.0`. It seems likely your package.json contains:

`"firebase-admin": "^115.0"`

When it should actually be:

`"firebase-admin": "^11.5"`

Try running:

`npm uninstall firebase-admin` & `npm install firebase-admin`

Answer (score 1):

The firebase installation script seems to have a problem with setting the version correctly. Try initializing a new project, and right when it asks you whether you want to resolve dependencies, you can manually change the package.json located in the subfolder it just initialized for you at your selected path, and replace 115.0 with 11.5. Then type y and it will continue as it should.